# How to enable autoindex in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Can't find the configuration for enabling the auto index. I am using community edition version  3.0.3 
 when I run the following code:

```
START bob=node:user(username='Bob'),charlie=node:user(username='Charlie')
```

`MATCH (bob)-[e:EMAILED]->(charlie)`
`RETURN e`

Gives the error

> Neo.ClientError.Schema.IndexNotFound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first enable auto indexing in `neo4j.conf`:

```
dbms.auto_index.nodes.enabled=true
dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys=username
```

See [table 144 on this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#_jmx_beans) in the docs for more info